# RX2 exception in EventLoopScheduler

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

We have immigrated from RX1.1.11111.1 to RX 2.0.20823.2. And now we have encountered a rare exception from the EventLoopScheduler:

```
an Unhandled Exception occured in non UI thread.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler.Run()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Does anyone have a guess what is the problem? Is it because we didn't use onError delegate and one of our methods failed?

Here's the gist of the code:

EventLoopScheduler m_scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();

.
.
.

m_receivedMessageHandler.StatusReceived.ObserveOn(m_scheduler)
    .Subscribe(p_unit => sendAll(m_retransmitManager, m_endPoint));

Can an exception inside sendAll cause this behavior?

Comment: Probably, but without seeing any of your code, or extended stack trace information, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The spelling correction was possibly worthwhile, but some actual code that causes the error would be definitely worthwhile. Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an onError handler in Subscribe otherwise the app will crash. If you don't care about the error then just eat it and don't do anything. I had the same error once so I did

```
            var subscription = observable.Subscribe(
                onNext: (v) => DoSomethingWith(v),
                onError: (Exception e) => {
                    // Just eat and log the exception.
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            );
```

when I didn't care about the exception. It's better to explicitly ignore the error and/or log it somewhere if it is a real problem.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. OnError should terminate the sequence if it is not handled with a linq catch statement.